# JDBC Template randomly returning empty result sets

Tags: java, spring, ms-access, tomcat, jdbctemplate

I have been racking my brain on this one for a while now with no luck.

**Background:**
I have a Java Web application running Spring MVC on Tomcat 8. I have a standard JBDC connector configured  in my server.xml file as follows (I have omitted the connection string):

```
auth="Container"
type="javax.sql.DataSource"
driverClassName="easysoft.sql.jobDriver"
initialSize="2"
maxTotal="3"
minIdle="1"
maxIdle="2"
maxWaitMillis="30000" 
removeAbandonedOnBorrow="true"
removeAbandonedTimeout="300"
logAbandoned="true"
validationQuery="SELECT 1"
```

The data source is a MS Access .ACCDB file

I am using JDBCTemplate to execute my prepared statements.

I have been using this set up for over 3 years and have never experienced the issue I am now facing.

**The problem:**
After a random amount of time (hours, days, weeks... nothing consistent), my query begins to send back an empty result set. The data is not changing, there should be data coming back but it just keeps coming back empty. Then after a few more (minutes, hours... also random), the query begins to send back the appropriate result set. Restarting Tomcat also fixes the issue immediately. Nothing is evidently out of the ordinary when this issue occurs.

**Additional Info**

I have been monitoring this issue for about 2 months using jConsole to check on JVM stats, and JMX mBeans of the connection itself and nothing is out of the ordinary.

There are also two other Access DataSources in the mix that are not experiencing this issue with the exact same configuration, located on the same server and would be getting queried just as often as the problematic data source.

No errors are being logged, (memory, connection pool, SQL errors) the result set just starts coming up empty.

Im looking for any feedback or thoughts one where else I could be looking to figure out whats going on.

Comment: The symptoms of your problem are somewhat vague, but connection pool issues is what actually comes to mind first here.  It sounds like maybe you can't even get a connection, and this is the reason of the empty result set.  The same query (on the same database) run against the same table should _always_ return the same result set, period.

Comment: You could try another access-jdbc-driver, I used ucanaccess. for accessing ms-access-dbs a while ago. http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I suspect the connection pool as well. I have been tweaking the configuration to see if the symptoms change in any way and again, nothing consistent. The same configuration can result in completely different times when the issue starts and stops. And if the connection is failing to be retrieved, would I not see these errors in my logs?

Comment: I suggest using a different database. H2 is entirely Java based. And supports concurrent users.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch not an option right now. The web app primarily uses its own MS SQL database for the majority of its functionality and were only reading from the access db. We also use an off the shelf application with very specific and limited functionality that uses this Access database.

Comment: @TomStroemer I have looked into ucanaccess in the past but it doesnt work for my situation. The access files I work with are large and I recall ucanaccess actually loads the whole db into memory which destroys performance for me.

Comment: *We also use an off the shelf application with very specific and limited functionality that uses this Access database.* So your off the shelf application is sharing the database with your custom Spring application?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch my custom Spring application reads from the access files the off the shelf application uses, it does not write. It has been doing so for many years. An old Struts application used to do this and I replaced that system with the current Spring application 3 years ago. This is the first time we've experienced this problem. Also, both systems are using the same, appropriate access drives in case you were thinking of that.

Comment: I have never been able to get the architecture you describe to work reliably. I have attempted it in the past. Corrupted the Access database, and re architected my solution to actually work. I don't know how your old struts application managed it.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch we did encounter corrupted database issues a few years ago but it turned out to be our system used outdated access drivers. Updating the drivers to match the off the shelf app fixed the issue and we've never had those problems since. We are fully aware that this off the shelf software is not cutting anymore and have been looking into alternatives for some time but its not an easy task.

Answer (score 0):

Well I finally corrected this issue.

I don't fully understand why this behavior is occurring, maybe one of you know and can provide some insight.

In the access table I am querying, records are stored with an ID as an Integer datatype.

When querying this table, I use a prepared statement passing an INT (the id) to match the datatype the table uses.

Turns out, this periodically results in a mismatch. While analyzing the mismatch I noticed that the returned records were coming back with ID's containing the numbers of the ID I was directly searching. For example, while searching for record 307, I would sometimes get record 3075 or 3078. The odd thing was it wouldn't return both 307 and 3075 records... just one or the other. So in my case, when the results started coming back empty, it was because this incorrect ID was getting queried.

I examined the id parameter in every layer of my system right down to the final query the prepared statement executed and that ID never changed. I was scratching my head...

So I decided to change my prepared statement to use a String value of the ID instead of an INT and I started getting consistent results.

TLDR;

Access datatype INT was not consistently returning results when searching by INT. Searching by String resulted in consistent data.